# Filtering what goes into my array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a program that reads a .txt file and stores each word into an array. I have this so far. it stores alright...

```
        BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(50);
        String[] line;
        String str;
        while((str=fr.readLine()) != null)
        {
            line = str.split("(?s)\\s+");
            for(String word : line)
                words.add(word);
        }
        if(words.size() > 49){
            System.out.println("To many words in file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
       for(String word : words){

            if(word.length() > 12){

            }
        }
        // Printing the content of words
        for(String word : words)
            System.out.println("sting entry:" + word);
    }
```

but it stores too much. When I used:

```
 for(String word : words)
     System.out.println("sting entry:" + word);
```

to check and see what all was being stored, I got this as the result:

```
sting entry:it's
sting entry:yes-man
sting entry:murdered
sting entry:ok
sting entry:
sting entry:Hello
sting entry:Friend
```

which is fine, except it reads the return value as a word and stores it in the array. How do I prevent this?

Also while I'm at it... if you notice some random code in my code:

```
   for(String word : words){

        if(word.length() > 12){

        }
    }
```

I want to make it so the `ArrayList` will also not store a string value that has more than 12 characters. How do I implement this, as well? Many thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in your code, do something like:

```
for (String word : line)
{
  word = word.trim();
  if (word.length > 0 && word.length <= 12) { words.add(word); }
}
```

You can put other filters in there as well, and check for too many words at the point
that you know you're going to put the word in the list if there's room.

Comment: So what is word.trim() doing here?